# NLP Email Validation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, nlp

If I have a set of emails which I retrieve from a Hive Table called users in this spark code below:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("YOUR_APP_NAME").setMaster("local[10]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)

hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris", "METASTORE_URI_NAME_HERE")

val df = hiveContext.sql("SELECT email FROM USERS")
```

Now df consists of a dataframe with one row of all email addresses. Is there a way in scala where I can validate the email addresses for example something like this: (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email) except this one is in python I need one in scala. Or would NLP be a good use case for this as well?

I am stuck on how to validate these email addresses and I need more than some Regex. I need a way to check if the domain of the email address has an SMTP server.

Something like this (except in scala):

```
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',check_smtp_connection = True)
```

Comment: question is actually "how to validate email in scala", and answer is the same as for "how to validate email in java"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely don't need natural language processing to validate email. You should use `javamail` for that, it supports SMTP validation.

Also note that the only possible way to check if email *really* exists -- send user unique link and ask to follow it.

Comment: Can you give me some pointers on how I use `javamail`. Basically I do not know in the emails if the domain even exists in the first place. Like I can get emails like `1234.com` or `jsdklfj@jsdaklf.com`. So basically the pipeline is first I need to check if the domain exists, then I need to "send them some unique link and ask to follow it" like you stated. Is there some sample code I can follow to achieve this?

Comment: To verify SMTP server credentials, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060837/validate-smtp-server-credentials-using-java-without-actually-sending-mail. But you cannot check if given email exists, only if it *may* exist. That can be done with something like http://crunchify.com/how-to-validate-email-address-using-java-mail-api/. However, as I wrote in the answer, the only reliable check is to ask user to follow some already sent unique link.

Comment: Hello sorry for the late response but can you please explain a little more by what you mean by "ask user to follow some already sent unique link." So if the user does click on that link how will I get that notification? Is that what you are trying to say I implement? Is that feature in `javamail`?

Comment: Yes, user should click on link. Usually some special controller is created to track those clicks (you cannot expect to get response immediately, but hours/days). To my knowledge, `javamail` does not have this built-in.

Comment: Okay will take a look into that. Thank you for the input and pointers!